# changing page direction to right-to-left in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf, reportico

I' developing a web base reporting application using php and reportico.I want to make reports in Farsi(Persian) so I need to change the direction of PDF files(From left-to-right, to rght-to-left).is there any supprot for that in FPDF, or any solution to solve it in reportico?

Answer (score 1):

See this URL i think it very help full.

http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/31/

**OR Try it.**

Description : This extension allows to print rotated and sheared (i.e. distorted like in italic) text.

TextWithDirection(float x, float y, string txt [, string direction])

x: abscissa

y: ordinate

txt: text string

direction: one of the following values (R by default):

- R (Right): Left to Right
- U (Up): Bottom to Top
- D (Down): Top To Bottom
- L (Left): Right to Left

TextWithRotation(float x, float y, string txt, float txt_angle [, float font_angle])

x: abscissa

y: ordinate

txt: text string

txt_angle: angle of the text

font_angle: shear angle (0 by default)

**Source**

```
 <?php
require('fpdf.php');

class RPDF extends FPDF {

function TextWithDirection($x, $y, $txt, $direction='R')
{
    $txt=str_replace(')', '\\)', str_replace('(', '\\(', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $txt)));
    if ($direction=='R')
        $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f Tm (%s) Tj ET', 1, 0, 0, 1, $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    elseif ($direction=='L')
        $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f Tm (%s) Tj ET', -1, 0, 0, -1, $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    elseif ($direction=='U')
        $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f Tm (%s) Tj ET', 0, 1, -1, 0, $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    elseif ($direction=='D')
        $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f Tm (%s) Tj ET', 0, -1, 1, 0, $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    else
        $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f Td (%s) Tj ET', $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    if ($this->ColorFlag)
        $s='q '.$this->TextColor.' '.$s.' Q';
    $this->_out($s);
}

function TextWithRotation($x, $y, $txt, $txt_angle, $font_angle=0)
{
    $txt=str_replace(')', '\\)', str_replace('(', '\\(', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $txt)));

    $font_angle+=90+$txt_angle;
    $txt_angle*=M_PI/180;
    $font_angle*=M_PI/180;

    $txt_dx=cos($txt_angle);
    $txt_dy=sin($txt_angle);
    $font_dx=cos($font_angle);
    $font_dy=sin($font_angle);

    $s=sprintf('BT %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f Tm (%s) Tj ET',
             $txt_dx, $txt_dy, $font_dx, $font_dy,
             $x*$this->k, ($this->h-$y)*$this->k, $txt);
    if ($this->ColorFlag)
        $s='q '.$this->TextColor.' '.$s.' Q';
    $this->_out($s);
}

}

?>
```

**Example**

```
 <?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('rpdf.php');

$pdf=new RPDF();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 40);
$pdf->TextWithRotation(50, 65, 'Hello', 45, -45);
$pdf->SetFontSize(30);
$pdf->TextWithDirection(110, 50, 'world!', 'L');
$pdf->TextWithDirection(110, 50, 'world!', 'U');
$pdf->TextWithDirection(110, 50, 'world!', 'R');
$pdf->TextWithDirection(110, 50, 'world!', 'D');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

output:- http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex31.pdf

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want to change the direction of whole page...do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution to offer, But you can always change the method itself,  Since it is using **Cell** method (which supports alignment), You only have to do the $align parameter on the method and then change all the lines which are printing the text.

(There are six places which it must be replaced, The **last** part is a little tricky)

Also Please consider that I have just made the changes And you may have to fix a few bugs, But Here is what **Write** method would look like in the end,

```
function Write($h, $txt, $link='', $align='L')
{
    // Output text in flowing mode
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;

    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin);
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    if ($this->unifontSubset) {
        $nb = mb_strlen($s, 'UTF-8');
        if($nb==1 && $s==" ") {
            $this->x += $this->GetStringWidth($s);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        $nb = strlen($s);
    }
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $nl = 1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        // Get next character
        if ($this->unifontSubset) {
            $c = mb_substr($s,$i,1,'UTF-8');
        }
        else {
            $c = $s[$i];
        }
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            // Explicit line break
            if ($this->unifontSubset) {
                $this->Cell($w,$h,mb_substr($s,$j,$i-$j,'UTF-8'),0,2,$align,0,$link);
            }
            else {
                $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),0,2,$align,0,$link);
            }
            $i++;
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            if($nl==1)
            {
                $this->x = $this->lMargin;
                $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
                $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin);
            }
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep = $i;

        if ($this->unifontSubset) { $l += $this->GetStringWidth($c); }
        else { $l += $cw[$c]*$this->FontSize/1000; }

        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            // Automatic line break
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($this->x>$this->lMargin)
                {
                    // Move to next line
                    $this->x = $this->lMargin;
                    $this->y += $h;
                    $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
                    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin);
                    $i++;
                    $nl++;
                    continue;
                }
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
                if ($this->unifontSubset) {
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,mb_substr($s,$j,$i-$j,'UTF-8'),0,2,$align,0,$link);
                }
                else {
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),0,2,$align,0,$link);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($this->unifontSubset) {
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,mb_substr($s,$j,$sep-$j,'UTF-8'),0,2,$align,0,$link);
                }
                else {
                    $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$sep-$j),0,2,$align,0,$link);
                }
                $i = $sep+1;
            }
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            if($nl==1)
            {
                $this->x = $this->lMargin;
                $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
                $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin);
            }
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    // Last chunk
    if($i!=$j) {
        if ($this->unifontSubset) {
            $this->Cell($w, $h,mb_substr($s,$j,$i-$j,'UTF-8'),0,0,$align,0,$link);
            // $this->Cell($l, $h,mb_substr($s,$j,$i-$j,'UTF-8'),0,0,'',0,$link);
        }
        else {
            $this->Cell($w, $h,substr($s,$j),0,0,$align,0,$link);
            // $this->Cell($l, $h,substr($s,$j),0,0,'',0,$link);
        }
    }
}
```